Why can't I scroll through images on connected Android devices on Windows 10?
My PC (Windows 10) has seemingly lost the ability to scroll images on connected android devices - in this case my phone, and my brother's phone too (Android 13 and 14). Both phones connect to the PC via USB-C cable and are recognized by Windows (using file transfer mode), but Window's Photo Viewer doesn't allow me to scroll through the images on either phone's storage (keyboard arrow keys don't work either)
I remember being able to do this not long ago, so something has changed.
I've gathered some random images in a folder to show what I mean. First screenshot is the folder on my PC (C:\Users\Me\Pictures\example) where scrolling works.

And here is the same image set on my HMD Pulse (This PC\HMD Pulse Pro\Internal shared storage\Download) showing how scrolling no longer works.

What I've tried so far:

Connecting via other modes (photo transfer, etc…).
Running CCleaner to try and clear some cache that might be responsible.
Trying other image viewers like ImageGlass and IrfanView.
Temporarily disabling anti-virus.


Have you tried the other connection modes from the phone, like MTP? Have you tried an alternative viewer utility? While the file contents of mobile devices APPEAR to be connected as regular file storage, this is only a result of Windows making them APPEAR to be this way. The PC is not interacting with the files on the phone in the same way you'd interact with a USB storage drive or a remote folder, and this will impact how certain things behave.

Scrolling doesn't work because USB MTP-based file management exists only within Explorer and not globally in the OS. Even though it looks "mostly" like a regular USB removable disk, it actually doesn't work anything like one.
That is, other programs cannot directly access the connected phone's files through a drive letter; instead Explorer needs to download the file to a temporary location before opening it in Photos or another app. If you click on the  button, you will see that the photo is actually in a temporary folder like C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Windows\INetCache or something like that – and that folder only has that one photo downloaded to it, thus there is nowhere to scroll.
The same will happen in PTP (photo transfer) mode, which is only a more limited variant of MTP.
As modern phones generally no longer support USB "Mass Storage" mode (i.e. disk mode), you'll need either some kind of remote access that would have OS-level integration – maybe the "Phone Link" thing that Windows keeps pushing, or some way to run a SMB file-sharing server on the phone (specifically SMB, not FTP)... or a photo viewer that has integrated support for MTP (but I don't know if any exist; I think they're all designed to just batch-import photos).

No supporting Mass Storage mode anymore seems like an unnecessary change; doesn't really improve anything as far as I can tell. But thanks for the information.

@TheReallyReallyLastScotsman: It makes a lot of things easier internally – for one, it doesn't require all apps (or even the entire OS) to completely shut down so that the filesystem could be dismounted internally before exposing it via USB; and it also allows the phone's storage (both internal and SD) to use more advanced filesystems than just FAT32. I think most Android phones these days use either Linux's ext4 or Samsung's F2FS internally, neither of which Windows would understand. (ext4 supports file-level encryption which Android uses heavily; same for APFS on iPhones.)

Can the developers on the Android side of this equation not simply expose all the contents of a selected folder so Windows can download it into the INetCache? I don't see why this issue can't be resolved.

The developers on the Android side are already doing so: with MTP. It's Explorer on the Windows side which doesn't download it. Android cannot force the entire folder to be pre-downloaded if Windows only wants to download one file.
